# What is name of the technique that adds CSS classes to an element?

Tags: html, css, terminology

Edit : Context is for HTML UI frameworks like Semantic UI etc, they have hundreds of styles predefined and one only needs to add them to the elements class, rather than write their own styles.

I need help with terminology,
I keep seeing examples of "adding" (not sure adding is the correct term) of classes to an element in HTML UI frameworks, for example, given an element with these class attributes:

```
class="mif-earth mif-2x"
```

To set it's background or foreground, all is needed is:

```
class="mif-earth mif-2x fg-green bg-blue"
```

Of course all the styles have been defined in the framework and are now being applied.

What is this type of programming called? is it declarative? Or does it not even have a name as it is just applying CSS as it was meant to?

Comment: There is no particular way to refer to this technique that I am aware of, other than "adding CSS classes to an element".

Comment: Maybe you could describe the context for your question. A bit more detail about the purpose of the terminology may help us provide better answers.

Comment: @torazaburo : yes, but the also have enumerated all the colors for forground, background, almost everything is pre-enumerated and all one needs todo is to just apply them, If it

Comment: Is the focus of your question that you are using styles that are pre-defined by the framework, or just that the styles are pre-defined by the css (ie. each element doesn't have all the styles written out in the markup)? 

Once again, I think you might be hitting on the idea of semantic markup, in that you are keeping the style description out of the actual markup.

Comment: @ChristopherMeyers : yes, semantic markup. The styles being pre defined and just being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML editing isn't really programming, exactly. HTML is a Markup language and that means you are marking up content. Markup is just really nouns and adjectives without any verbs or adverbs. Programming is making your content do something by putting some verbs on those nouns.

Adding a class to the markup would be meta information about that content. You may have heard of separating the description of your styles using meta attributes like classes as "being semantic" or something like a separation of style and content.

If you use a programming language like JavaScript to change the content or meta attributes, that is sometimes referred to as DOM Scripting.